# Why Android Studio External Libraries shows multiple version dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[image]

Even though I added an implementation explicitly

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.5.1'
```

and run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` to check the tree, and found all the version is replaced by the new one. Android Studio still show there exists three of them.

```
androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4 -> 1.5.1 (*)
```

Comment: Its possible that other third party libraries may have dependencies on those specific versions.

Comment: But the dependency tree already shows all third party libraries use the latest one. like `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4 -> 1.5.1 (*)`

Comment: @CodeAlien any idea why it shows? solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's showing multiple versions to notify us what happens if we remove one of the dependency.

For example in OP's case, if we remove all of:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.5.1'
```

Then `1.2.4` will be used instead (because something somewhere depends on that version).

> Of course, `1.2.4` will only be used if the dependency has not any + sign, like:
>
> ```
> implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4+'
> ```